# AWS Elastic Map Reduce: output to SimpleDB

Tags: hadoop, amazon-simpledb, elastic-map-reduce

What is the most efficient way to get Elastic Map Reduce output into SimpleDB?

I'm aware that I could just output the results to S3, download them, and have a script parse the results and insert into SimpleDB.

But is there an easier/faster way where I can directly insert EMR output into SimpleDB (for time and efficiency reasons)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer Page 12 of the following getting started document by Amazon, it has a section on "Storing data into Amazon SimpleDB" :  http://awsmedia.s3.amazonaws.com/pdf/introduction-to-amazon-elastic-mapreduce.pdf

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for. I'm surprised I couldn't find it anywhere else. (I have moved to another DB solution, but this is still good to know.)